# Is it possible to show a formatted message with bold and normal font?

Tags: delphi

I would like to show a formatted message with bold and normal font. Something like

lili **lala** lolo

Is it possible to do something like this with messageDLG or similar api ?

Comment: No, but you can always create [a custom dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4648758/how-to-display-a-table-in-showmessage) yourself. For instance, such a dialog could contain a `TRichEdit` control.

Comment: Yes, of course it's possible to use a bold font in a window with a button.  Is there anything in particular you need help with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question has somewhat already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4435865/display-simple-markup-in-a-label-in-delphi). They propose several solution, one of them I like is using a HTML label from [jVCL](https://wiki.delphi-jedi.org/wiki/JEDI_Visual_Component_Library). This component is `JvHTLabel`.

Using the HTML label, you can easily create a form with that label centered and a class method to create the form, set a caption, set the label text using simple HTML markup, show the form modal until the user click on OK/Cancel button you'll add as well.

Comment: thanks, It's a little sad their is no already ready made solution for this :(

Comment: If the q already an SO answer, what's the point in answering it again?